# latex() function not giving rendered output with R "rms" package

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, rendering

latex() function not giving rendered output between the code chunks with R "[rms](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rms/index.html)" package. How can I solve this?

**CODE**

```
library(rms)
getHdata(kprats)

#data
kprats$group = factor(kprats$group, 0:1, c('Group 1', 'Group 2'))
dd = datadist(kprats); options (datadist ="dd")

S = with(kprats, Surv (t, death ))
f = npsurv(S ~ group, stype = 1, ctype = 1, data = kprats)

#model
fw = psm(S ~ group, data =kprats, dist ='weibull')

#code for output
latex(fw, fi = "")
```

**OUTPUT**

[{\rm Prob}{T\geq t} = \exp[-\exp( \frac{\log(t)-X\beta}{0.1832976} )]{\rm \ \ where} \ ] \begin{eqnarray*} X\hat{\beta}= & & \ & & 5.450859 \ & & +0.131983[{\rm Group\ 2}] \ \end{eqnarray*} and ([c]=1) if subject is in group (c), 0 otherwise

**OUTPUT SHOULD BE AS FOLLOWS**

[image]

**R version**

```
           _                           
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
arch           x86_64                      
os             mingw32                     
system         x86_64, mingw32             
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          6.1                         
year           2019                        
month          07                          
day            05                          
svn rev        76782                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
nickname       Action of the Toes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `results='asis'` in the chunk header and do

```
require(rms)
options(prType='latex')

fw <- psm(...)
fw     # LaTeX output with fit statistics in a table
latex(fw)   # formula
```

`prType` only affects `print(fw)` not `latex(fw)`.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now the output transformed into latex code that works well while running it on an online calculator. Is there a way for seeing the result in Rstudio in a readable/non-latex code format (as on the formula picture in my original post)?

Comment: The report should show it in that format so I assume you are asking about RStudio's LaTeX preview capability.  I know that simple inline LaTeX is automatically previewed when you hover over it.  Not sure for longer LaTeX.